# Export HTML files from a SQLite 3 database (Ruby on Rails app)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, export

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, looking at using it for an app that I need to create. The story is:

I'm using `rails generate scaffold Page url:string parent:string content:text` to create a Page scaffold. So we can then input a URL (`hello-there.htm`), a parent (`my-folder`) and lots of text, images, etc for the page into a web form, and have it stored.

Once this is all in the SQLite database, it needs to be exported to lots of HTML files. So, on disk somewhere, I need each parent folder to be created, filled with HTML files which themselves contain the content (plus a static header/footer):

```
other-folder/index.htm
other-folder/another-file.htm
my-folder/hello-there.htm
```

Sorry, I know this is a really vague, hand-wavy question. My gut says I could/should use an Export view/controller (`localhost:3000/export`) which has a big button on it? But if you have something, anything I could read, it would be appreciated. Modifying the view for each page (`localhost:3000/pages/12`) is easy, but what do I do when I need loads of actual `.htm` files?

I wish I could post some code, but obviously there isn't any yet :(

Cheers,

Alex

---

Maran links to Webby below, which looks perfect for my needs!

Comment: Before you continue see if you are re-inventing the wheel; Check the link and see if you could use this intead http://webandy.com/articles/5-ruby-based-static-site-generators

Comment: Oh wow, these are absolutely beautiful. Thank you so, so much! I'm especially loving the look of Webby, but will investigate all and report back :). Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering this myself, just so that it shows up as answered)

[Maran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87305/maran) linked to [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/), a static site generator, in the comments. This was actually what I was looking for.